# Laravel Update with associative array

Tags: laravel

i created array from input array form by for loop

```
            $production_item_product_update = [];
            $production_item_inventory_update = [];

            for ($code = 0; $code < count($data->product_id); $code++) {
                $production_item_product_create[] = $data->product_id[$code];
                $production_item_inventory_create[] = [
                    'qty' => calculate_inventory_qty($data->product_id[$code], 0, Auth::user()->store_id),
                    'buy_price' => number_patch($data->buy_price_small[$code]),
                    'average_price' => calculate_inventory_average($data->product_id[$code], Auth::user()->store_id),
                ];
            }
```

then update by this code

```
inventory::where('store_id', Auth::user()->store_id)
                    ->whereIn('product_id', $production_item_product_update)
                    ->update($production_item_inventory_update);
```

give me this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `inventories` set `0` = {\"qty\":10,\"buy_price\":\"1.2574\",\"average_price\":32,\"single_price\":\"34\",\"multi_price\":\"34\",\"vip_price\":\"34\"} where `store_id` = 3 and `product_id` in (84))
```

Comment: update array must have the column name as the key and the value as the array value. in your case `$production_item_inventory_create` is just an array with int indexes, where at index 0, you have another array (I suppose the actual array which you should be sending to update). So, maybe, either loop again and call update or do the updating in this for loop without managing separate arrays?..

Comment: Thanks bro but how i can add index name?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your for loop

```
for ($code = 0; $code < count($data->product_id); $code++) {
$data = inventory::where('store_id', Auth::user()->store_id)
    ->whereIn('product_id', $production_item_product_update)
    ->update(
        'qty' => calculate_inventory_qty($data->product_id[$code], 0, Auth::user()->store_id),
        'buy_price' => number_patch($data->buy_price_small[$code]),
        'average_price' => calculate_inventory_average($data->product_id[$code], Auth::user()->store_id));
```

}

Comment: Thank bro but in this way always many duplicate query run